# justifyContent is not working in React, but alignItems worked fine

Tags: css, reactjs

While I was styling a footer div in React, I set the display to be flex. The alignItems property worked fine but the justifyContent did not with any value. I tried space-between, space-around, and space-evenly but the two elements remained close to each other. I tried setting specific dimensions to the img but that did not have any effects. Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
  <div className='footer'>
      <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-around', alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: '20px'}}>
        <img style={{width: '48px', height: '48px'}} src={logo} />
        <p>BODY SCULPTING</p>
      </div>
      <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-between', marginRight: '20px'}}>
        <img src={socialMedia} alt='social media icons' />
        <p>2022 - All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </div>

.footer{
  height: 187px;
  background-color: #8f8f8f;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: It is working fine!, Can you send the image of the output

Comment: I think there is not enough space **i.e** `width` for `justify-content` to work.

Comment: Yup, if the width of the container is smaller than or equal to the sum of the width of the flex items, won't see any effect

Comment: What is the size of the footer ?

Comment: add `width:100%` in your `.footer`

Comment: I was able to identify the issue thanks to @KrishnaAcharya

Answer (score 0):

[image: Output of code]

When I took a screenshot of my output in response to a user from the comments I was able to identify the issue.

It was due to setting a vertical alignment property on the parent div (align-items: center) which canceled out the vertical alignment property on child elements 1 & 2 with CSS property (justifyContent: 'space-around/space-between').